# Merging fields from two different document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I want to merge a field from the different document into 1 single document

For Example :

I have a collection like this

```
{ _id : 1 , data : [AccountID, CustID,Fname, Lname] }
{ _id : 2 , data : [AccountID,CustID,Fname,Lname] }
{ _id : 3 , data : [AccountID,CustID,Fname,Lname] }
```

I would want the above collection to be transformed as below

```
{ _id : 1 , 
data : [AccountID,CustID,Fname,Lname]
data1 : [AccountID,CustID,Fname,Lname]
data2 : [AccountID,CustID,Fname,Lname]
}
```

Please note, I'm trying to achieve this using MongoDB

It would be great if someone can help with this!